# How do I create a "Users by time of day" heatmap in Google Data Studio?

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I want to create a heatmap in Google Datastudio similar to the "Users by time of day" heatmap in Google Analytics.

This is how it looks in Google Analytics.
[image]

THE FIRST PROBLEM is that when I have my columns as the days of the week, it  sorts on ascending/descending value alphabetically, NOT Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, etc.

THE SECOND PROBLEM is that I can't actually get the heatmap coloring.

THE THIRD (not a problem, but a preference)...is there a way to group every 2 hours like Google Analytics does?

I am creating this using the PIVOT TABLE chart. Should I be using a different chart? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get something pretty close by doing this. Add a Pivot table, and modify the following settings.

Row Dimension  - Hour

Column Dimension  - Day of week

Metric - Users

Sort Row 1 - Hour - Ascending

Sort Column 1 - Day of Week Ascending

**Then under the Style tab**

Metric - change from Number to Heatmap

Comment: thanks for trying...when sorting on the day of week, it's not in order of days, but in alpha order. So Fri, Mon, Sat, Sun...

Comment: Are you using Day of Week, or Day of Week Name, I have no problem getting Day of Week to appear in the correct order Sunday to Saturday

Comment: The metric worked for heatmap...still stuck on sorting the days

Comment: I've recently written a tutorial on how to create this report in Data Studio. It includes the code for a calculated field to help sort days of the week correctly. There is also a link to the dashboard that I made publicly available for anyone to copy and apply their own data. Have a look here: https://businessahead.co.uk/users-by-time-of-day-google-analytics/

Comment: I don't see an "Hour" dimension in my report... Although it [should be there](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9143382#zippy=%2Ctime).

Answer (score 2):

For the 2h interval I solved it by going in to the data source editor, click count on hour then it creates a copy that takes a formula, so i entered the formula

```
CASE 
   WHEN HOUR IN ("00","01") THEN "00-02" 
   ...
   ...
   ...
   WHEN HOUR IN ("22","23") THEN "22-00" 
   ELSE "Other"
END
```

Answer (score 2):

I've recently written a tutorial on how to create this report in Data Studio.

As a summary, you need to use a "Pivot table with heatmap". Use Hour of Day as your Row Dimension, and a calculated field for Day of the Week as your Column Dimension. The code for the calculated field is in my post and it essentially adds a number before the name of the day so you can sort them alphabetically. Then, add your Metric: Sessions.

There is also a link to the dashboard that I made publicly available for anyone to copy and apply their own data.

The link to the post with step-by-step tutorial and access to dashboard template is: [businessahead.co.uk/users-by-time-of-day-google-analytics](https://businessahead.co.uk/users-by-time-of-day-google-analytics/)

[image: Users by time of day in Data Studio]